# How to get the value change using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code from a template I brought. I tried some of the answers on StackOverflow but I cannot get data from the option when it is changed. When user selects an option without out reload I have to insert new data to a `div`. but I can't figure out how to get data from this drop down.

```
<div class="drop-list-one">
    <div class="inner clearfix">
        <div class="dropdown-outer"><a class="btn-box dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" href="#">Default Sorting</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu4">
                <li><a href="#">Subjects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Timelines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Incomplete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you haven't tried anything? *"insert new data"*: which new data? *"...into a `div`"*: which `div`?

Comment: i just need the function to get the change value from the drop down. I know how to populate the data into the div. I can figure out how to get the data from the dropdown(dropdown value)

Comment: @pedram, please don't make edits where you destroy the indentation of code.

Comment: Here is `ul li` not `select option` there is no `value`

Comment: @trincot indentation  should cleared, no need for this here. Do not ask please with your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function () {
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
    }) ;

</script>
```

Comment: awesome. This is what i need